# laravel Illegal string offset to get array andis on blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

after get data from database with this code:

```
$recipes = ContentCategories::find('12')->contents->take(4);
```

and showing first items of `$recipes` with:

```
dd($recipes[0]->featured_images['thumbnail']);
```

i get this result:

```
"/uploads/contents/63648415249878355.jpg"
```

full result:

```
array:2 [▼
  "images" => array:1 [▼
    "original" => "/uploads/contents/63648415249878355.jpg"
  ]
  "thumbnail" => "/uploads/contents/63648415249878355.jpg"
]
```

now when i try to show `$recipes` on blade with `@foreach` i can't show `thumbnail` and i get this error:

```
Illegal string offset 'thumbnail'
```

my code on blade:

```
@foreach($recipes as $recipe)
    <img src="{{$serverInformation->address}}{{$recipe->featured_images['thumbnail']}}"/>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Try do die and dump whole array, ther must be an error in structure

Comment: Could it be that 1 element in your list of recipes does not have the thumbnail-key in the array?

Comment: @dbrumann all of array items have thumbnail key

Comment: @AdamKozlowski how can i test that?

Comment: simple: dd($recipes)

Comment: @AdamKozlowski i used that and pasted on post `dd($recipes[0]->featured_images['thumbnail']);`